# Components of a Tomcat access log

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

Sample Tomcat access log:

```
192.168.124.27 - - [10/Oct/2013:00:03:16 +0530] "GET /scripts/dmenu.js HTTP/1.1" 200 25797
```

Following are the stuff that I understand:

- 192.168.124.27 - IP Address
- [10/Oct/2013:00:03:16 +0530] - Timestamp
- GET - Method
- /scripts/dmenu.js - URI Path

I don't understand what is meant  by the other components in this log for example:

- HTTP/1.1
- 200
- 25797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"GET /scripts/dmenu.js HTTP/1.1" is the request line as per RFC 2616

200 is the response code

25797 is the size of the response in bytes

For full details see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve